# Importing flex compiled swf into a flash file

Tags: apache-flex, import, adobe, flash

I've built a form in Flex.

- When I run the flex project, I get a html file with some js, css and **swf files** (NOT A SINGLE FILE), swz files.
- When I run the main swf file alone, many things are working perfectly except at places where it needs to send a HTTPService request.
- When I use the html file, all works fine.

Now I want to do the following.

- Import this form made in flex into a flash site (actionscript 3)
- This form has various ViewStacks, where the user will be travelling through these. I want to reload the form back to its initial stage when the user wants to fill the fields again.
- Can there be any request sent to the Flash Site from this FORM, regarding the form submission  success ?
- Can I compile the Flex Project to one single swf file, so that I can use this swf file without any Browser?
- Can I convert the webpage application Flex Project to an Adobe AIR application ?

Details: 
I used flash builder 4... and flex 3 coding as in

`<mx:Application/>`

mx namespace is "http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
and no "s", or "fx" namespaces defined.

Comment: Voting to close.  We are not here to do the work for you.  We are here to answer questions.  Try to do research first, then if you have *a* question, you can ask it and we'll answer it.  Don't just dump all your questions into one post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't answer all your questions, but I can answer:

> Import this form made in flex into a flash site (actionscript 3)

I don't see why not, although I never did that myself; typically it's the other way around as Flex swf are really more applications than regular flash swf typically are.

> Can I compile the Flex Project to one single swf file, so that I can
>   use this swf file without any Browser?

Yes you can:

- With Flash Builder, go to Project->Properties->Flex Build Path, and
  change Framework Linkage to Merge Into Code
- When invoking the mxmlc compiler directly, use the option -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true

> Can I convert the webpage application Flex Project to an Adobe AIR
>   application ?

Yes you can by right-clicking your project in the Package Explorer window, and under Add/Change Project Type, you get make your project an Air application.